# How to attach a bluetooth controller to a Pixel 4 Phone

Tags: android, bluetooth

Is it possible to attach a bluetooth controller to Pixel4?
I have successfully attached a bluetooth controller(/dev/ttyACM0) to Linux. And It works fine for me. Currently has been tested with scanner, adveritise, and GATT pair features.

Now the next step is to attach the bluetooth controller to Android Pixel 4 Phone to continue my work
I briefly checked with AOSP, there is a file:
hardware/qcom/sdm845/bt/libbt-vendor/include/vnd_mako.txt:1:BLUETOOTH_UART_DEVICE_PORT = "/dev/smd3"
from my understanding, I need to change /dev/smd3 to /dev/ttyACMx. Unfortunatelly, this is for Pixel 3.

Does anyone give me some suggestion on how to attach to Pixel4?
Or correct my understanding of attach a bluetooth controller to an Android Phone?